# How do i remove big white space created by CSS Grid

Tags: css, grid, gallery

I am creating a simple CSS Grid of 3 columns and 2 rows to display a gallery and then my content would follow but i realize that the Grid has included big white space which i am struggling to remove.

After the *.gallery-container* div, Css Grid inserts a **very huge** space before the Hello world content comes.

I want to get rid of the huge space that gets inserted before the hello world content. Please help. Source code here

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ced939dd3b40fb365ed3f6522571ae9920191117134820/0d4757

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Gallery</title>

    <style>

        .wrapper{
            width:50%;
            margin:auto;
        }

        .gallery-container {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
            grid-template-rows: 25% 25%;
            gap: 4px;
            padding:20px; 
        }

        .gallery-div img {
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            object-fit: cover;
            display:block;
        }

    </style>


  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="wrapper">

        <div class="gallery-container">

            <div class="gallery-div" ><img src='img/1.jpeg' alt="img" /></div>
            <div class="gallery-div" ><img src='img/2.jpeg' alt="img" /></div>
            <div class="gallery-div" ><img src='img/3.jpeg' alt="img" /></div>
            <div class="gallery-div" ><img src='img/4.jpeg' alt="img" /></div>
            <div class="gallery-div" ><img src='img/5.jpeg' alt="img" /></div>
            <div class="gallery-div" ><img src='img/6.jpeg' alt="img" /></div>

        </div>

        <div>
            <h1>Hello World</h1>
        </div>

    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi @IsaacNewton as others already answered, the problem is generated by the css property `grid-template-rows`, but I would like to explore other solutions.

Why the percentage value cause this problem? Because when you set up the value in percentage automatically it's taking the 25% of it's parent content, the element 'gallery-container' in your case. source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp

How could the problem be solved?

- Change the percentage value to 50% in `grid-template-rows`, in this way you fill the 100% of the parent element.
- You can use the value in `fr`. `fr` stay for `flex` and each flex-sized element takes a share of the remaining space. So for example `grid-template-rows: 25% 25%;` would fit the remaining 50% equally. source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-rows

I've also created an example that solve your issue with `fr` in the following link https://codepen.io/RaySoy/pen/YzzdymB . Feel free to use it for test the `grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;`, too.

Let me know if it's solve your issues or if you found other solutions.

Comment: changing grid-template-rows to 50% 50% solved the problem. I also set the height of the .gallery-container manually in px to help make my images appear smaller. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

it's caused by `grid-template-rows: 25% 25%;` because in this way you are saying "of this grid, assign 25% as height for each line" so it understand that after those 2 rows, there should be another 50% of something... you should use `grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;` and set the height manually to `.gallery-container`

Comment: Hi AlbertoSinigaglia, I have given it a try but still could not resolve. My source code could be downloaded here https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ced939dd3b40fb365ed3f6522571ae9920191117134820/0d4757

Comment: sorry, there wasn't that gap without the images, edited the answer

Comment: changing grid-template-rows to 50% 50% solved the problem. I also set the height of the .gallery-container manually in px to help make my images appear smaller. Thank you very much

Comment: No problem... just in case, leave an upvote to each question that helps you, that improve the community

Comment: I have done that but because my reputation is less than 15, it says it is recorded but  it does not change the publicly displayed upvote score.